# Show a popup from a popup in DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke-9, dotnetnuke

In DNN is it possible to navigate to a different popup control from another popup control?

I have a pop up edit control with some buttons. When I click on one of the buttons I would like to show a different edit control in the pop up window.

I have tried using this code in the button's click handler:

```
Response.Redirect(EditUrl("", "", "MyControlKey"))
```

but when I click the button Firefox shows a "Corrupted Content Error" in the pop up window.

Can this be made to work, and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I figured it out. This seems to do what I want:

```
Dim url = DotNetNuke.Common.NavigateURL("MyControlKey", $"mid={ModuleId}", "popUp=true")
Response.Redirect(url)
```